# Socket Exception: socket is closed

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I want to create server which is able to be connected with multiple clients.
My main function is:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5556);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MakaoServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    while (true) {
        try {
            Socket connection = serverSocket.accept();
            PlayerConnection playerConn = new PlayerConnection(connection);
            playerConn.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Nie można było utworzyć gniazda.");
        }
    }
```

PlayerConnection is a Thread class. The run method:

```
public void run() {
    InputStream input = null;
    while (true) {
        try {
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            String msg = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(msg);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PlayerConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {

        }
    }
}
```

When I run client and send message to server it's received but on the next while loop iteration connection.getInputStream(); throws an Socket Exception socket is closed. Why?

```
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
at makaoserver.PlayerConnection.run(PlayerConnection.java:38)
```

Comment: Your read loop should terminate when `readLine()` returns `null`. At present you will get an endless stream of `null` messages when the peer closes the connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the input stream and buffered reader outside the loop.

Possibly creating multiple stream connected to the same input stream is causing this.

Comment: But I want to get more than one message from client. If you put input stream and buffered reader outside the loop I will only get one message.

Comment: No once you have a handle to the input stream you don't need to keep initialising it. Your readline will still be in the loop to collect messages.

Comment: Can you remove the logger and put a e.printStackTrace and print the trace here

Comment: I think your client is closing connection. Nothing seems wrong with server code. Can you also paste your client code? You still need to move the input stream buffered reader initial out of the loop

Comment: Creating multiple streams does not cause this problem. Closing them does.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public void run() {
    InputStream input = null;
    input = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

    while (true) {
        try {
            String msg = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(msg);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PlayerConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {

        }
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to close sockets when your done with them

```
try {
  // Create objects
  // do stuff
} finally {
  if (obj != null) obj.close();
}
```

Comment: I've done it but I still get the same exception.

Comment: You said that the connection closed exception was thrown on the connection.getInputStream() in the second pass through the loop. this line is no longer in the loop, where is the exception being thrown now? Also could you please show some of the code from PlayerConnection as you might be closing the connection from the server side.

Comment: I solved the issue. :) I was opening also an OutputStream it caused exception.

Comment: @latata, why opening an `OutputStream` caused the socket to get closed?

Comment: This code will spin forever at end of stream. It need a null check on the result of `readLine()`.