# Why my Java server close sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, client

I have server and client.
My server acepts  all connections and  returns to client string. 
But when I try to send more  lines  its  crashed with

`java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
        at java.net.Socket.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
        at server.ServerCore.hiMsg(ServerCore.java:67)
        at server.ServerCore.run(ServerCore.java:49)`

Here is it my Server Code :

```
package server;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author pisio
 */
public class ServerCore extends Thread {

    private LoadSettings loadSettings = LoadSettings.Init();
    private int port = loadSettings.getConfigInt("port");
    private int max_connections = loadSettings.getConfigInt("max_connections");
    private String ipServer = loadSettings.getConfig("ipServer");
    private ServerSocket socket;
    private Socket connection;
    private boolean serverRuning = false;
    private int connectedUsers = 0;
    private Vector connVector = new Vector();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            socket = new ServerSocket(port, max_connections);
            System.out.println("+++\t Server was started at  address:" + socket.getLocalSocketAddress() + " with posible max users " + max_connections);

            serverRuning = true;

            while (serverRuning) {
                if (connectedUsers <= max_connections) {
                    connection = socket.accept();
                    connection.setKeepAlive(serverRuning);
                    connVector.add(connection);
                    connectedUsers = connVector.size();
                    hiMsg();
                    hiMsg();
                    hiMsg();

                }

                System.out.println("+++\t Last User:" + connVector.get(connVector.size() - 1).toString());
            }


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //   Logger.getLogger(ServerCore.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void hiMsg() {

        try {
            Socket c = (Socket) connVector.get(connVector.size() - 1);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(c.getOutputStream()));
            out.write("Hi user !  Im server !  Your master !  Blow me down\nping: ?  PONG ?");
            out.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerCore.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void stopServer() {
        statusServer();
        serverRuning = false;
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(ServerCore.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("+++++\t  SERVER WAS STOPED !");
        // System.exit(port);

    }

    public void statusServer() {
        if (serverRuning) {
            System.out.println("Server running at port:" + port + "  with connected users :" + connectedUsers + "/" + max_connections);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Server IS NOT RUNNING!");
        }
    }
}
```

And Here is it my  client code :

```
package meetingsclient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.String;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ServerConnect {

    private static ServerConnect sc = null;
    private Socket socket = null;

    private ServerConnect() {

        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 8080);

            sendHiMsg();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerConnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    private void sendHiMsg() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


        System.out.println("Input:" + in.readLine());


    }

    public static ServerConnect Init() {
        if (sc == null) {
            sc = new ServerConnect();
        }
        return ServerConnect.sc;
    }
}
```

I readed  this topic : [Socket Exception: socket is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263141/socket-exception-socket-is-closed)   but  this dotn helped me.
// Sorry for the links , but  I cant understand how properly to format my code here.

Comment: Don't use pastebin. Post only the relevant part of your code directly in your question. If you feel the need to use pastebin, it is a clear indication that you are trying to post way more code that you probably need and should.

Comment: I cant format my code here. Doesnt work. I think this is not a big problem. Next time I will try to paste it here.

Comment: You sure can format your code here. Actually, your code is automatically formatted for you. You can navigate a little bit around here to see that most questions (and answers) contain formatter code samples. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Okey , 10x for the links. I fixed it.
So Can we now slove my problem with  closed  socket ?

Comment: you are very rude for a newcomer, aren't you? There are rules, there is etiquette, and if you want help from the community, you have to follow all of that.

Comment: I apologize. I made a mistake. You gave me guidance, I read, I tried and I was able to format the text. Right? Sorry if I look from countries like jackanapes. The problem that previously described harassing me than a few days.
Again, I'm sorry. As you can see my take lessons and try to do everything the community wants it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [javadoc of `getOutputStream()` in `Socket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html):

> Closing the returned OutputStream will close the associated socket.

Also, closing a `PrintWriter` (and all other Printers/Writers) close their underlying streams as well. So, you are closing your `OutputStream` by closing the `PrintWriter` (in `hiMsg()`) and then trying to write to the socket, which was closed.

To fix the problem, don't close the `PrintWriter`. Garbage collection will take care of it for you! But do close the socket when you are done with it.

Comment: If I remove the   `out.close();`  it dont sends the information to the client.

Comment: Isn't that the point? If you mean it doesn't send it - then try with `out.flush();` instead, which ensures it flushes (sends)!

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will  reconstructed  my Vector to escape from this to close PrintWriter

Comment: This is the way  I  reconstructed my Server, and  for now its work.
`private class ConnectionU {

        public Socket socket;
        public BufferedReader br;
        public PrintWriter pw;

        public ConnectionU(Socket s) {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
   
        }

        public PrintWriter getPrintWriter() {
            return pw;
        }

        public BufferedReader getBufferedReader() {
            return br;
        }
    }`